# how to change postgresql password if my username contains period

Tags: postgresql

I want to change my pg/sql pwd using the syntax

```
alter user username WITH PASSWORD '*****';
```

The problem is that my user name contains a period, like `user.name`, and it seems the system doesn't allow a period in user name.

So how can I change my password?

Answer (score 19):

You have to **double-quote** otherwise illegal identifiers.

```
ALTER USER "a.b" WITH PASSWORD '*****';
```

My standing advice: use **legal** identifiers without double-quotes exclusively if at all possible.

Read [the manual about identifier syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Excellent! Then you should click the checkmark on Erwin's answer here to give him credit for the correct solution.